# "I am a student studying my master's degree in Major A at University A, with achievement of a bachelor's degree in Major B at University B."

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

After looking up the dictionary and searching keywords on Google I failed to find the exact thing I want to express. I made this sentence up. I am not sure if I can use the phrase "with achievement of" in this manner. [Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22with%20the%20achievement%20of%22) do not appear to be relevant to my context.

I asked on [WordReference and some people there suggest](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/with-the-achievement-of-a-bachelors-degree.3735980/) I use *"having obtained my degree"* or *"after obtaining my degree"*. But I still wonder if it sounds natural with the usage of "achievement" in a sentence introducing my academic background in an internship cover letter?

> I am a student studying my master's degree in Major A at University A, **with the achievement of** a bachelor's degree in Major B at University B?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Keep in mind that when your question gets closed, **do not** post it again to circumvent the closure. You should read the closure reason, understand why it was closed, edit your question and wait for it to be opened. Read this [Help Center article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a matter of making the title specific. I'll read the details carefully.

Comment: What your question lacks is just a little bit more information telling us any research you have done (for example you can show us you've Googled "with the achievement of" and what you have found out). Questions without any information besides "Is this natural?" "Is this grammatical?" are off-topic because we want people to show their research effort. This is not a bad question, just needs a little more information. I notice you also ask on ELU. The same goes for your ELU questions (so far some of your ELU questions show fairly good context).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks for reminding me. There are generally two kinds of questions for me when learning English, those for understanding and those for expressing. It's easier to explain the point I don't understand with the context. But when it comes to expressing sometimes it's quite difficult for me to guess what the appropriate expression might be, because my mother tongue is totally different with English from structure to detail.

Comment: So after looking up the dictionary and searching keywords on Google and finally failed to find the exact thing I want to express, I tried to make the sentence by myself and post to ask for help. May I ask if there are other better ways for me to ask questions on this website when I want to express something but don't know the natural expression?

Comment: I've edited your question with the information you provided in the comments and what I found online and reopened it. I also deleted the old question. With this I am giving you an example of what quality questions with reasonable context should look like. If you've asked the same question elsewhere, I recommend you include that piece of information in your question. It is always a good idea to include as much information as you can here, because you will then get more specific answers and the answers will then be able to explain to you the exact things you don't understand.

Comment: As you are new, allow me to say that generally, we are not supposed to do editing here. But I just chose to help you because I know how hard things get sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work. Perhaps

> *I am a student studying **for** my Master's degree in Major A at University A, **having earned** a Bachelor's degree in Major B at University B*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a present for you:

I am studying for a Master's Degree in [x] at [University B] after completing [or earning] my Bachelor's Degree in [z] at [University A].

*there is no need to say student! You cannot study for an MA unless you are a student.

**A compound sentence is best here.**